# Downgrade a Verizon Google Pixel Phone to older versions?

Tags: downgrade, google-pixel

I'm planning to buy a Google Pixel off ebay.

Does the Verizon Google Pixel allow downgrading of software?

I like to try older & newer versions for development purposes?

Comment: You should be able to unlock the bootloader using [dePixel8](http://theroot.ninja/depixel8.html) unless the phone comes with Android 7.1.1 or higher. Otherwise with a locked bootloader there's not much to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not purchasing a Verizon Pixel if looking for a unlocked bootloader. I think since around December Verizon has pushed out updates that make it imposdible to unlock. Everything I've read says there's no way to unlock them if updated, and most of them have been.

I own a Verizon Pixel and was so sure I did not want to root...

Answer (score -1):

The Pixel has an unlocked bootloader. You can flash different system images if you feel comfortable enough flashing files. Otherwise, try appetize.io for a good app test. it has many different versions of Android and iOS for all types of devices.

Comment: The Verizon version's bootloader cannot be unlocked.